# Currency format in window c#

Tags: c#

Desktop window application.

I have textbox in which user give values in numbers.

what i want ,when user enter amount in textbox and after leaving that textbox amount should convert into indian currency format.
For example .If i enter 12345678 then output will be  1,23,45,678.00

Thanks

Comment: What code do you have so far? And what problem are you having?

Comment: I think you want custom formatting like `#,##,##,###.00`

Comment: yes @V4Vendetta i want custom formatting.I have used the above format "#,##,##,###.00" .I have written the following code:  textBox1.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(12345678).ToString("#,##,##,###.00"); // and the output of this is "12,345,678.00" but i want the output like this "1,23,45,678.00"

Comment: @jim i want custom formatting.I have used the above format "#,##,##,###.00" .I have written the following code:  textBox1.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(12345678).ToString("#,##,##,###.00"); // and the output of this is "12,345,678.00" but i want the output like this "1,23,45,678.00"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value.ToString("C"); is enough to convert to currency format.
```

For details look into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ebe5aks.aspx

```
value.ToString("N");  // Without $ sign , converts to default numeric format

 value.ToString("##,##,##,###.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //As the default format is en-US you need to convert it to the Indian format.
```

Comment: sorry i am getting this output $12,345,678.00 but i want 1,23,45,678.00

Comment: pardon.. what do u get when use it..? $[value] this is how u ll get.

Comment: then use "N" , value.ToString("N")

Comment: i am using the above code "value.ToString("C")" like this : string str = Convert.ToDouble(12345678).ToString("C");
           textBox1.text = str;  output of this is "$12,345,678.00" which is wrong

Comment: use "N" instead of "C". that $ won't come.

Comment: on using "N" ,i am getting this out put: 12,345,678.00 but i need 1,23,45,678.00.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`decimal moneyvalue = 1921.39m;
string html = String.Format("Order Total: {0:C}", moneyvalue);
Console.WriteLine(html.Replace("$",""));`

This is just an example complete implementation depends on your code

Comment: sorry i am getting wrong output = "Order Total: $12,345,678.00" instead of this output should be 1,23,45,678.00. this is an Indian currency format.

Answer (score 0):

```
string theAmmount = "123456789123";
int ammountLength = theAmmount.ToString().Length;
theAmmount = theAmmount.Insert(ammountLength - 2, ".");
double ammountDouble = Convert.ToDouble(theAmmount);
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
string ammountString = string.Format(cultureInfo, "{0:C}", ammountDouble);
string g = ammountString.Substring(4);
```

Comment: usually it's better to accompany the code in your answer with some description...