# Convert int to Price/Money/Currency (C#)

Tags: c#, .net

I have some prices in my DB which are stored as data type `money` and have the following code:

```
result.RangeMinimum = (decimal)ad.RangeMinimum;
result.RangeMaximum = (decimal)ad.RangeMaximum;
```

The output is:

`38000`
and
`42000`

Ideally, what I want is something [exactly] like this:
`38, 000.00`
and
`42, 000.00`

How can I achieve this? I mean, is there already an existing class out there that's built into the .NET framework or something?

Comment: The code you've given doesn't have output - certainly not in a text form. You haven't shown where you're *formatting* those values.

Comment: chk this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887225/currency-format-in-window-c-sharp/9887391#9887391

Comment: You're right. I was a little distracted while writing my question and left out the part that formats the values. I'll update it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to achieve can be done through custom numeric format, i.e., for the 
`ToString()` method or the `String.Format()` method

[MDSN Custom Numeric Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f74fd32-6c6b-48ed-8241-3c2b86dea5f4%28v=vs.90%29)

Comment: +1 though you might want to flesh out your comment a little. STack overflow likes answers to contain actual solutions and not just links to resources if possible.

Comment: Sunrisas, you should put some more information from the link, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Jason specified "exactly", and there is a space after the coma ... That is not a standard numeric format afaik.

Comment: @TeddHansen - I'm sorry, I know I said "exactly", but, I was taught in School that having a space after the comma is standard. Were they wrong?

Comment: @Sunrisas - that link says "Content Not Found - We're sorry, but the page you requested could not be found. Please check your typing and try again, or use the search option on this page."

Comment: @Sunrisas it's ok, I just noticed the un-linked brace at the end.

Comment: Jason: It depends on your use. If you only want a standard representation of it there are many standard formats to use, but then you should be careful on using the word "exactly". :)

Comment: No worries @TeddHansen - no complaints here, was just curious. :)

Answer (score 3):

As you specified "exactly" and have a space after the coma it seems standard numeric formats will not work. You can easily customize your own format using `String.Format`.

```
Decimal number = 38000.01m;
string formatted = string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:#, ###.00}", number);
// formatted now contains "38, 000.01"
```

Output is: `38, 000.01`

Please always remember cultureinfo so us non-US citizens can enjoy apps. :)

Information on formatting with Custom Numberic Format can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Note the 00's at the end, they force two digits. Depending on your use you may or may not want this behavour. Replace with ## if required. Also if you use this in a loop don't to a culture lookup on every call to string.Format.

Answer (score 2):

You can format it like

```
string.Format("{0:#,#.##}", decimalValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string currencyString = result.RangeMinimum.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
result.ToString("N");
```

using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` u can define your own format

Answer (score 1):

Try
    
          decimal ad.RangeMinimum = Decimal.Parse(result.RangeMinimum.ToString("#0.00"));